# what kinda of SQL is it? TODATE(), TOCHAR(), isdateformat()

Tags: sql

I am working on a aggregator and it contain build in functions which are I am not familiar with. Few are these I listed here, does anyone know what SQL format is it?

- `TODATE(string, in_format[, out_format])`
- `ISDATEFORMAT(value[,date_format])`
- `TOCHAR(numeric_value)`

Also, here is how I use it, it does accepting my syntax, but it didn't return correct value.

```
count(where text_column != TODATE('date_format','YYYY-MM-DD', 'yyyymm'))
```

Comment: What is your database  ?

Comment: @Indent: I think that is Steven's question

Comment: I tried to Google `ISDATEFORMAT()` and `TOCHAR()`, but I didn't find any particular database which utilized those functions. The only thing I found was `Visual Basic` or `C#`. Could you post the whole query, and the "surroundings", i.e. do you make the call from Management studio as a query, or from a script?

Comment: DB it's an Oracle but I am using a Tool called "Trinity JFDesigner" which is very rare to see. I think it's a data intergration tool. http://us.trinity-data.com/

Comment: @StevenHuang    Why are you asking which system you use, when you know that it is Oracle? That should be in the OP.

Comment: my purpose is to COUNT records that has not fall within the report run month (txdate is a build in variable representing the date that runs the report) TXDATE (format: YYYY-MM-DD) and to show you more build in variable ${last01txdate} means txdate -1 because of that "01" within the variable

Comment: @Cenderze DB is in Oracle but DB tool we are using is not!  that's why it gives me headache

Comment: Never saw a database allowing a WHERE statement in a COUNT statement

Comment: @RaymondNijland because you mention it, I have moved out the WHERE statement and change it to "count (text_column) where (text_column) != TODATE('date_format', 'yyyy-mm-dd', 'yyyymm')" but by doing this, I can not get a numeric date type return. Also this sql return "true" value back! weird...

Answer (score 0):

for `TODATE(string, in_format[, out_format])`you can use `TODATE('20171114','YYYYMMDD')`
for `ISDATEFORMAT(value[,date_format])` `ISDATEFORMAT("2017-06-15", "%M %d %Y")`

and `tochar` function converts a number or date to a string. e.g

`TO_CHAR(1210.73, '9,999.99')

Result: ' 1,210.73'`

Comment: I know how each works, but it does nothing good for my purpose. I want to compare a text with a date and return to numeric data type..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out line of code that works:
sum(DECODE(text_column, DATETOCHAR('date_column','yyyy-mm-dd','yyyymm'),0,1))

So add on top of my original question. What type of SQL is function 'Datatochar'!?